# Nginx RTMP and PHP Authentication

Tags: php, nginx, rtmp

I am trying to create an authentication script for the Nginx RTMP module. I am making it with PHP, I want to to verify the username and streamkey match up with the one in the database, so far I have:

**auth.php**

```
<?php 
$streamer = $_GET['name'];
$streamid = $_GET['key'];
mysqli_connect('localhost', 'streamblur', 'password', 'streamblur');
$sqlstreamid = mysqli_query("SELECT streamkey FROM members WHERE username = '$streamer'"); 
if ($sqlstreamid == $streamid) {
    http_response_code(200);
} else {
    http_response_code(401);
}
?>
```

**nginx.conf**

```
rtmp {
    server {
            listen 1935;
            chunk_size 4096;

            application push {
                    live on;
                    record off;
                    on_play http://localhost/auth.php;
                    notify_method get;
            }   
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Sammitch It is not working, when I connect to the server it just gives me an error.

Comment: That is all relevant information that you need to include in the question.